# Global variable not working, help out a noob

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, global-variables

```
import random


#--------------------------------------------------------------------#



tieCount = 0
lossCount = 0
winCount = 0
totalPoint = 10
i = 3



#--------------------------------------------------------------------#



def cpuFire(userInput, points):
    if userInput == 0: 
        totalPoint = totalPoint + int(0)
        tieCount = tieCount + 1
        lossCount = lossCount + 0
        winCount = winCount + 0
        cpuChoice = "fire"
        wlt = "t"
    elif userInput == 1:
        totalPoint = totalPoint + int(points * -1)
        tieCount = tieCount + 0
        lossCount = lossCount + 1
        winCount = winCount + 0   
        cpuChoice = "fire"
        wlt = "l"
    elif userInput == 2:
        totalPoint = totalPoint + int(points)
        tieCount = tieCount + 0
        lossCount = lossCount + 0
        winCount = winCount + 1   
        cpuChoice = "fire"
        wlt = "w"



def cpuGrass(userInput, points):
    if userInput == 1: 
        print("Tie! Your points remain unchanged")
        totalPoint = totalPoint + int(0)
        tieCount = tieCount + 1
        lossCount = lossCount + 0
        winCount = winCount + 0   
        cpuChoice = "grass"    
        wlt = "t"
    elif userInput == 2:
        print("You lost the game with X points deducted.")
        totalPoint = totalPoint + int(points * -1)
        tieCount = tieCount + 0
        lossCount = lossCount + 1
        winCount = winCount + 0    
        cpuChoice = "grass"  
        wlt = "l"
    elif userInput == 0:
        print("You won the game with X points added.")
        totalPoint = totalPoint + int(points)
        tieCount = tieCount + 0
        lossCount = lossCount + 0
        winCount = winCount + 1     
        cpuChoice = "grass"  
        wlt = "w"

def cpuWater(userInput, points):
    if userInput == 2:
        print("Tie! Your points remain unchanged")
        totalPoint = totalPoint + int(0)
        tieCount = tieCount + 1
        lossCount = lossCount + 0
        winCount = winCount + 0 
        cpuChoice = "water"  
        wlt = "t"
    elif userInput == 0:
        print("You lost the game with X points deducted.")
        totalPoint = totalPoint + int(points * -1)
        tieCount = tieCount + 0
        lossCount = lossCount + 1
        winCount = winCount + 0  
        cpuChoice = "water" 
        wlt = "l"
    elif userInput == 1:
        print("You won the game with X points added.")
        totalPoint = totalPoint + int(points)
        tieCount = tieCount + 0
        lossCount = lossCount + 0
        winCount = winCount + 1  
        cpuChoice = "water" 
        wlt = "w"

def cpuRand():
    cpuList = ["f","g","w"]
    rand = random.choice(cpuList)
    if rand == "f":
        cpuFire(userInput, points)
    elif rand == "g":
        cpuGrass(userInput, points)
    elif rand == "w":
        cpuWater(userInput, points)



#--------------------------------------------------------------------#



while i > 0:
    print("You have " + str(totalPoint) + " points.")
    points = int(input("Enter the number of points to be used for next game: "))
    if points > totalPoint:
        print("You do not have neough points.")
        i = i - 0
    else:
        userInput = int(input("Enter 0(fire), 1(grass) or 2(water): "))
        if userInput > 2 or userInput < 0:
            print("You entered an invalid option, you lost!")
            break
        else:
            cpuRand()
            if wlt == "t":
                print("draw!")
            elif wlt == "l":
                print("You are " + str(userInput) + " and computer is " + str(cpuChoice) + ", you lost!")
            elif wlt == "w":
                print("You are " + str(userInput) + " and computer is " + str(cpuChoice) + ", you won!")
            i = i - 1
```

I am trying to help a friend out with their assignment, and I keep getting an error

local variable 'totalPoint' referenced before assignment

I have tried putting global totalPoint within the first line of the functions, outside of it and on the top of the code. I can't make this work, how do I solve it?

Comment: When I ran the code, the program printed out "You have 10 points. Enter..." Could you point out where, in the code, your program is breaking?

Answer (score 1):

While you can access global variables without the global keyword, if you want to modify them you have to use the global keyword. For example:

```py
def cpuFire(userInput, points):

    # if you want to modify the global variable you need to add this to each local scope
    global totalPoint

    if userInput == 0: 
        totalPoint = totalPoint + int(0)
        tieCount = tieCount + 1
        lossCount = lossCount + 0
        winCount = winCount + 0
        cpuChoice = "fire"
        wlt = "t"
    elif userInput == 1:
        totalPoint = totalPoint + int(points * -1)
        tieCount = tieCount + 0
        lossCount = lossCount + 1
        winCount = winCount + 0   
        cpuChoice = "fire"
        wlt = "l"
    elif userInput == 2:
        totalPoint = totalPoint + int(points)
        tieCount = tieCount + 0
        lossCount = lossCount + 0
        winCount = winCount + 1   
        cpuChoice = "fire"
        wlt = "w"
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the variable outside all the functions will by default result in a global variable. However, if you want to create a global variable within a function, then you have to use the global keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I put my global var inside the if and elif statements, I should put it at the beginning of the function def